# where can i get Request.Browser.Platform items from?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to have pre-made list of most common OSes in my DB and all non default to be listed as other. Problem is i don't know what OSes called in Request.Browser object.

List i want to have WinXP, Vista, Win7, Linux, MacOS and other...

Do any of you know what are exact names of these OSes in Request.Browser.Platform or where i can get list of values from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually part of the user-agent string:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Comment: I'm not sure Request.Browser.Platform has same values as UserAgent. Simply because Request.Browser.Platform shows my OS as WinXP while UserAgent shows Windows XP. So it's quite unusable...

Comment: My understanding is that browsers only return the user-agent string. Using Fiddler seems to confirm this. If that's correct then I believe the Platform property is parsed by ASP.Net from the user-agent. There isn't anywhere else it could come from. It would seem the user-agent parser is 'standardising' the text.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own, maybe i my question was wrong. I wanted list of default OSes returned either from Request.Browser.Platform or Request["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] so i can enter those into DB.

I've got the list and wrote a function to check what kind of OS user uses.

```
    public static string getOsFromUserAgent(string userAgent)
{
    string visitorOS = "other";
    Dictionary<string, string> osNamesAndRegexes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    osNamesAndRegexes.Add("Windows 98", "(Windows 98)|(Win98)");
    osNamesAndRegexes.Add("Windows XP", "(Windows NT 5.1)|(Windows XP)");
    osNamesAndRegexes.Add("Windows Vista", "(Windows NT 6.0)");
    osNamesAndRegexes.Add("Windows 7", "(Windows NT 7.0)");
    osNamesAndRegexes.Add("Linux", "(Linux)|(X11)");
    osNamesAndRegexes.Add("Mac OS", "(Mac_PowerPC)|(Macintosh)");

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvpPair in osNamesAndRegexes)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(userAgent, kvpPair.Value, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            visitorOS = kvpPair.Key;
        }
    }
    return visitorOS;
}
```